# How do I stop the same 'random' rows being selected across different computers?

Tags: r, random, sample

I have some code which requires several simulations and I am hoping to run across separate computers. Each simulation requires identifying a random subset of the data to then run the analyses on. When I try to run this on separate computers at the same time, I get notice that the same rows are selected for each simulation. So if I am running 3 simulations, each simulation will identify the same 'random' samples across separatae computers. I am not sure why this is, can anyone suggest any code to get around this?

I show the sample_n function in dplyr below, but the same thing happened using the 'sample' function in Base R. Thanks in advance.

```
library(dplyr)
explanatory <- c(1,2,3,4,3,2,4,5,6,7,8,5,4,3)
response <- c(3,4,5,4,5,6,4,6,7,8,6,10,11,9)

A <- data.frame(explanatory,response)
B <- data.frame(explanatory,response)
C <- data.frame(explanatory,response)

for(i in 1:3)
{
 Rand_A = sample_n(A,8)
 Rand_B = sample_n(B,8)
 Rand_C = sample_n(C,8)
 Rand_All = rbind(Rand_A, Rand_B,Rand_C)
}
```

Comment: Do you set a seed in an earlier part of the code?

Comment: No I don't currently. Do I need to this this before the simulation? How do I go about this?

Comment: If you are not setting a seed I find it odd that you get the same rows selected as it would use the computer clock for the seed.  Can't explain that.  What about it you were to just set different seeds for each computer?  Set seed using:  set.seed(123).  Different numbers for each run...

Comment: This might be why as I start the simulations at virtually the same time (within 10 seconds). set.seed may be a good explanation, will try now, thanks. If this works, I'll recomment and let you answer below so I can tick

Comment: This appears to have done the trick thanks @brb - feel free to post answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the seed for each computer separately as brb suggests above. You could also have this happen automatically by setting the seed to the computer's ip address, which would eliminate the need to edit your script for each computer. One implementation using the `ipify` [package](https://github.com/gregce/ipify):

```r
library(devtools)
install_github("gregce/ipify")
library(ipify)

set.seed(as.numeric(gsub("[.]","",get_ip())))
```